# Compose - How to know when a sub-composable has been rendered

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle, composable

Working on Compose, I'm trying to know when a sub-composable has been rendered to start my `LaunchEffect`

Here's a little snippet of what I'm trying to achieve :

```kotlin
fun MyCompo(
    screen: @Composable (Modifier) -> Unit,
) {
    val fr = remember { FocusRequester() }
    screen(Modifier.focusRequester(fr))

    LaunchEffect(Unit) {
        fr.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

My `LaunchEffect` is crashing because it's launched before `screen()` had time to render.

Any idea how to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a callback to your screen Composable and invoking it from LaunchedEffect from screen implementation? Does this work?

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    screen: @Composable (Modifier, ()->Unit) -> Unit,
) {
    val fr = remember { FocusRequester() }
    screen(Modifier.focusRequester(fr)) {
        println("Child Composable")
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        println("Parent Composable")

        fr.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

And invoking it

```
MyComposable { modifier, onComposed->
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Red)) {

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
            onComposed()
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Yep that's what I did in the end, but it's actually what I wanted to avoid. In fact in my case that's ok because something I forgot is that I have a network call. So I have to wait anyway and notify back MyCompo.